# Golang PKCS12 sign with inter intermediate certificate

Tags: go, cryptography, x509

I have .p12 extension which contains certificate and passkey. Then I extract cert and key in PEM using these commands:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in <filename>.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out passcertificate.pem -passin pass:<password>

openssl pkcs12 -in Certificates.p12 -nocerts -out passkey.pem -passin pass:<password> -passout pass:<password_out>
```

After all I sign file with private key and intermediate cert to get signature.

```
openssl smime -binary -sign -certfile <intermediate>.pem -signer passcertificate.pem -inkey passkey.pem -in manifest.json -out signature -outform DER -passin pass:<password_out>
```

Is this **possible** to reproduce these steps in Go using standard library?

```
// read file content to be signed
content, err := ioutil.ReadFile(".../path_to_file/manifest.json")
if err != nil {
    //
}
// read .p12 file
buf, err := ioutil.ReadFile(".../path_to_file/Certificate.p12")
if err != nil {
    //
}
// extract key and cert
pk, cert, err := pkcs12.Decode(buf, password)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
privateKey := pk.(*rsa.PrivateKey)
// create hash
h := crypto.SHA256.New()
_, err = h.Write(content)
if err != nil {
    //
}
hashed := h.Sum(nil)
// how to pass intermediate cert??
sign, err := rsa.SignPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, privateKey, crypto.SHA256, 
hashed)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
sig := base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodeToString(sign)
```

Comment: A raw signature doesn't contain a certificate. It's just the statically sized, binary result of the modular exponentiation of the message hash + padding. If you want to include an X.509 certificate then you should look for an PKCS#7 / CMS / SMIME library (PKCS#7 is the standard, CMS - or Cryptographic Message Syntax - is the official name and SMIME is what it was designed for - secure mail). [Here](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2315) is the RFC.

Comment: [See also](https://godoc.org/?q=pkcs7)